# Tornado on pika consumer can't run

Tags: python-2.7, rabbitmq, tornado, producer-consumer, pika

I want to build monitoring system using RabbitMQ and Tornado. I can run the producer and my consumer can consume the data on queue but the data cant be show on website.

This just my experiment before I using the sensor

```
import pika
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
import logging
from threading import Thread

logging.basicConfig(lvl=logging.INFO)
clients=[]

credentials = pika.credentials.PlainCredentials('ayub','ayub')
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('192.168.43.101',
                                5672,
                                '/',
                                credentials))
channel = connection.channel()

def threaded_rmq():
    channel.basic_consume('Queue',
                            on_message_callback= consumer_callback,
                            auto_ack=True,
                            exclusive=False,
                            consumer_tag=None,
                            arguments=None)

    channel.start_consuming()

def disconect_rmq():
    channel.stop_consuming()
    Connection.close()
    logging.info('Disconnected from broker')

def consumer_callback(ch,method,properties,body):
    for itm in clients:
        itm.write_message(body)
class SocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        logging.info('websocket open')
        clients.remove(self)

    def close(self):
        logging.info('websocket closed')
        clients.remove(self)

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("websocket.html")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/ws',SocketHandler),
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

def startTornado():
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

def stopTornado():
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.info('starting thread RMQ')

    threadRMQ = Thread(target=threaded_rmq)
    threadRMQ.start()
    logging.info('starting thread tornado')

    threadTornado = Thread(target=startTornado)
    threadTornado.start()

    try:
        raw_input("server ready")
    except SyntaxError:
        pass
    try:
        logging.info('disconnected')
        disconnect_rmq()
    except Exception, e:
        pass
    stopTornado()
```

but I got this error

```
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /favicon.ico (192.168.43.10) 0.98ms
```

please help me

Comment: If your question was answered please mark it as [solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `SocketHandler.open` function you need to add the client not remove it.
Also consider using a `set` for clients instead of a `list` because the remove operation will be faster:

```py
clients = set()
...
class SocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        logging.info('websocket open')
        clients.add(self)

    def close(self):
        logging.info('websocket closed')
        clients.remove(self)
```

The message you get regarding `favicon.ico` is actually a warning and it's harmless (the browser is requesting an icon to show for web application but won't complain if none is available).

You might also run into threading issues because Tornado and Pika are running in different threads so you will have to synchronize them; you can use Tornado's  `IOLoop.add_callback` method for that.